# Globally check for admin login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing ASP.Net MVC application. I have a login form for Admins. When an Admin logged in, it is redirected to home page.

Now when I click on `Employee` menu, it redirects to `Employee/Index`. In the `Index` method, I am checking whether Admin is logged in. I have to check in every method of `Employee` controller for admin login.

Is there any way to check for the admin login for all the admin area. Here admin can create, update, delete Employees, Store etc. So is there any way to check adminlogin just once instead all the method of Index, Create, Delete, Edit?

Anything like

```
// Controller of EmployeeController
public EmployeeController()
{
    if (Session["Admin"] == null)
    {
        // return to AdminLogin
    }
}
```

Because when I enter `url` in browser - `localhost:9999/Admin/Employee/Create`, it is redirected to Create page, without login. I don't want to check in all methods of a controller.

Comment: Ive updated you title to reflect your question - as it was it read like an XY Problem, you thought the solution to this question was to return a result from a constructor (?) - Its not, but in ASP.NET MVC your question has a very standardized solution.

Comment: Are you using Identity?If yes, decorate your action methods with [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]

Comment: I have stored `Usesrname` and `password` in database.

Comment: so you have created your own custom tables to store user data, not the one provided by identity(which will create tables for us)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply **Autorize attribute** on the action methods or controller class you need and check for admin role like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

There is detailed discussion on that question in [asp.net mvc and check for if a user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484786/asp-net-mvc-and-check-for-if-a-user-is-logged-in).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid typos especially in case of using `Authorize` I will recommend having a static class for the `Roles`

```
 public static class Roles
    {
        public const string Admin = "Admin";
    }
```

Then when decorating you can do this;

```
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.Admin)]
```

Because you don't want retyping `"Admin"` everytime which could lead to a bug in your code when you make typo.